# Podcast #5 - The military

Tags: discussion, podcast

[This episode](https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast-s01-e05) focuses on the Military

Throughout the world, we are inundated with images and stories about militaries, their exploits and capabilities, but are these claims really true. This presents a special challenge for skeptics because a lot of military information is classified, and in many cases military organizations intentionally deceive. Although some questions are easy to determine answers to

## Questions

- [Is it possible to fly 4 helicopters anywhere in a country without official knowledge?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/is-it-possible-to-fly-4-helicopters-anywhere-in-a-country-without-official-knowl)
- [Does Disney have the third largest navy in the world?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12388/does-disney-have-the-third-largest-navy-in-the-world)
- [Has France ever won a war?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/has-france-ever-won-a-war)
- [Were there army experiments to give humans infrared vision?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/were-there-army-experiments-to-give-humans-infrared-vision?s=1|1.8945)

## Hot Questions

- [Will global warming reduce available oxygen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/will-global-warming-reduce-available-oxygen)
- [Do EnChroma glasses "cure" color-blindness?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/do-enchroma-glasses-cure-color-blindness)
- [Do 60% of Americans believe a third major political party is needed?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/do-60-of-americans-believe-a-third-major-political-party-is-needed)

## User Shout Outs

Top Users:  [user568458](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/10630/user568458), [Thomas Francois](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/32262/thomas-francois), [Polygnome](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/34611/polygnome), [DavePhD](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/25579/davephd)
Welcome New user:  [Sarcastron](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/34651/sarcastron)

We are always open to feedback, so don't hesitate to contact us
Is there any specific subject you want us to look into? Send us suggestions.

Comment: Note: Podcast #4 had recording issues, which is why it has not been released.

Comment: Wow, Larian didn't mention this at all last we spoke. This is fun stuff. Thanks for doing this.

Comment: Dumb question, but are the Questions + Hot Questions + User Shoutouts the outline of the podcast?

Comment: @HC_ yes, it's the sources we use

Comment: @HC_ By the way, they mention in the podcast that if you want to see something different to contact them. I don't have any ideas right now, but I may call Steve and give him some in the future.